# Unit measurement of variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have two variables, all are ordinal variable but with difference unit measurement

1. Generalized trust                                | 1-4
2. Participation in the Communist Party of Vietnam, | 0-36

If I rescale these variables by applying proportion of maximum scaling (POMS) rescaling method

```
             Xi − Xminimum
POMS =   -------------------------.   (2)
           Xmaximum − Xminimum
```

to have these variable  have the same values range from 0 to 1. Does this make these variables have the same unite measurement?

Comment: This is definitely not possible. Because 37 is not divisble by 4. If the second variable was 1 to 36 and each point in the second variable corresponds to 0.02702703, and it follows that each point in the first variable corresponds to 0.02702703*9= 0.25. Then both the variables after POMS transformation will be the same. Obviously, this is correct up to proportionality not only for the units I came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing makes two variables have the same "unit measurement".  You can make variables have the same range, you can make them have the same standard deviation, you can make them have the same mean .... whichever you like or other options too.

But your two variables are measuring different things.  The units aren't going to be the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I find this answer very helpful.

Comment: In that case, you might want to accept my answer.